# How to create a keyboard shorcut for an app on the start screen (Windows 8.1)?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut for an app that I have on the start menu ?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the app and choose **Open File Location**
2. Right click on the file for the app you have chosen and click **Properties**
3. Click in the box named **Shortcut key** and type a letter